# IE9 - unwanted padding inside div when inner div is absolute and outer div is relatively positioned

Tags: css, internet-explorer, sass

I have been battling this problem for a good 6 hours now on IE. There seems to be extra padding when we use the before tag with position to be absolute.

**CSS**

```
.rteEditable{
  background-color:green;
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 400px;
  min-height: 400px;
}
.rteEditable p{
  padding-left: 46px;
}

.rteEditable:before{
  position: absolute; 
  height: 100%;
  width: 40px;
  content:'';
  background-color:red;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="rteEditable" contenteditable="true">
<p>
HELLO THIS IS A TEAST
</p>
</div>
```

The code I have written [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/c7dzL2h2/1/)

Here are images for better explanation.

[image: Google Chrome]

Chrome

[image: IE9]

IE9

Comment: Not able to replicate on IE11

Comment: Yeah can't replicated on IE11 only on IE9 or lower (not sure on IE10)

Comment: Try to put margin:0 and pading:0 to your elements and any extra padding or margin on top of it. Also put margin:0, padding:0 to your html,body.

Answer (score 0):

See https://jsfiddle.net/evouvj7v/

Add

```
left: 0;
right: 0;
top: 0;
bottom: 0;
```